# Mentally calculate the first 9 terms of this Fibonacci sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, mental-arithmetic

There was a question in a mental math test and it expected me to calculate the first 9 terms of the following  Fibonacci sequence (Note that this is how the problem was exactly given.):

The sum of the first nine terms of the Fibonacci sequence 4,7,11,18,29... is

How could I have done this in under 15 seconds?
I know that if there are n terms, then $2F_n+F_{n-1}=$ Sum of $n$ Fibonacci numbers. But even this is too tedious for me.

Comment: Do you really need to do it in $15$ seconds? It looks very intense.

Comment: @MonsieurGalois I really have to do it in 7 seconds, but that is way too fast for me.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck It's mental math.

Comment: To make that in less than $10$ seconds you must know how to do it before seeing.

Comment: Maybe they only ask him the answer.

Comment: @MonsieurGalois Quite true. The tests I take for my high school sometimes repeat typically hard problems. I suspect this is one of them! I will not know yet until a couple of months from now when I take the next test.

Comment: @MonsieurGalois The answer is all that is necessary.

Comment: Do you need to calculate the terms, or the sum of the terms.  You listed five of them.  Getting four more in $15$ seconds should not be hard.  Adding them all in that time is not out of the question if you have paper to write them down.  Trying to keep all $9$ in mind is hard.  If I needed the sum mentally I would keep the sum and the last two terms in mind, so I would start 4,7,11, sum so far=22, 18, sum=40, and so on.  I wouldn't worry about whether I would be done because there isn't time for that.  I suspect it would be chancy.

Answer (score 7):

Notice that

$$F_n-F_{n-1}=F_{n-2}$$

So

\begin{align*}
F_9=F_{11}-\color{magenta}{F_{10}}\\
F_8=\color{magenta}{F_{10}}-\color{red}{F_9}\\
F_7=\color{red}{F_9}-\color{blue}{F_8}\\
F_6=\color{blue}{F_8}-\color{green}{F_7}\\
F_5=\color{green}{F_7}-\color{purple}{F_6}\\
F_4=\color{purple}{F_6}-\color{orange}{F_5}\\
F_3=\color{orange}{F_5}-\color{yellow}{F_4}\\
F_2=\color{yellow}{F_4}-\color{pink}{F_3}\\
F_1=\color{pink}{F_3}-{F_2}\\
\end{align*}

So the sum of all is $F_{11}-F_2$

Comment: Well I see that your answer had a massive transformation.:)

Comment: Even with this I wasn't able to do that sum in 15 seconds.

Comment: Yes @SchrodingersCat , when I was doing the color labels I noticed that sum. I saw before that you added the same answer.

Comment: (That's the reason of why I upvoted you after writing correctly)

Comment: Obliged and honoured..  :)

Answer (score 5):

Fibonacci sequence follows the recurrence relation:
$$F_{n+1}=F_{n}+F_{n-1}$$
And this can be re-arranged as
$$F_{n-1}=F_{n+1}-F_{n}$$

Now using this, your sum will become a  telescopic series. See if you can complete it now.

**UPDATE:** As mentioned by MonsieurGalois, it turns out to be $F_{11}-F_2$.

**ADDENDUM:** In general, it must be kept in mind (for a generalised expression) that the sum of the first $n $ terms of the Fibonacci sequence gives the sum as $F_{n+2}-F_2$.

Comment: You can also use $F_n=g_{k+1}F_{n-k}+g_kF_{n-k-1}$ where $g_n$ is the $n$th standard Fibonacci number $(g_0=0, g_1=1).$  So $F_{11}=g_6F_6+g_5F_5=(8)(47)+(5)(29)=521,$ which of course you can do  mentally in 3 seconds .LOL

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you know the standard Fibonacci numbers by heart.  The others have shown that the sum of the first $9$ terms is the eleventh term minus the second.  You can use the linearity of the recurrence to say that the series that begins $4,7$ is four times the series that begins $1,1$ plus three times the series that begins $0,1$, which is the same as the usual series offset downward by $1$.  Thus if we use $F_n$ for the standard Fibonacci numbers, your sum is $4F_{11}-4F_2 +3F_{10}-3F_1=4\cdot 89 - 4 \cdot 1 +3 \cdot 55 -3 \cdot 1=514$

Comment: It doesn't take more time doing the multiplication than the sums? Even if you know the first $11$ fibonacci numbers, you do $4$ multiplications and then $3$ sums. In the other cases you do $7$ sums (the ones to get the elements of the sequence and the final substraction).

Comment: I don't know which approach you will find fastest.  You could easily spend more than 15 seconds choosing one.  Given the problem, it would take me longer than 15 seconds to derive the $F_{11}-F_2$ rule and the fastest thing would be direct calculation.  This can be a useful approach in the right circumstances.